# Android gradle - Content is not allowed in Prolog

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am strugglint to build my Android App. I didnt add any dependecies and tried to clean my project. Still getting this error

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0.
     Required by:
         DogApp:app:unspecified > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0
      > Could not resolve com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0.
         > Could not parse POM C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\animated-vector-drawable\25.0.0\animated-vector-drawable-25.0.0.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

The file pom is empty. I have no idea how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Is your Support repository installed and up to date?

Comment: Should be, I downloaded a new version today, it might be the reason why it isnt working because it stopped during downloading because of little space

Comment: I have just updated to version 40. It didnt help

Answer (score 0):

I solved by updating the support repository again.